# SQL statement is returning the top value rather than the correct value

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have these tables with practice questions that are asked, but I am running into some issues. The first question asks "Find the first name and last name of the student who has the highest GPA in CIS415 in Fall 2019."

The tables that are needed to find the correct values:

- `Students` (**SID**, Firstname, Lastname, Age, Email, Phone) //SID = Student ID
- `Courses` (**CID**, Name, Capacity) //CID = Course ID
- `Enrolls` (**CID**, **SID**, Semester, GPA)

The SQL statement I have currently is:

```
 SELECT Firstname, Lastname 
 FROM students 
 JOIN Enrolls ON student.sid = enrolls.sid 
 GROUP BY CID, Semester 
 HAVING MAX(GPA) 
    AND CID = 'CIS415' 
    AND semester = 'Fall2019';
```

I believe it is just pulling the students firstname and lastname from the top of the table. I am unsure of the problem and would love some input. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [S].[Firstname], [S].[Lastname]
FROM    Students [S]

        INNER JOIN Enrolls [E]
            ON [S].[SID] = [E].[SID]

        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  MAX( [GPA] )    AS [GPA],
                    [CID]           AS [CID],
                    [SID]           AS [SID]
            FROM    Enrolls [E2]
            GROUP BY
                    [CID], [SID]
        ) [DT]
        ON  [E].[CID] = [DT].[CID]
        AND [E].[SID] = [DT].[SID]


WHERE
      [E].[CID] = 'CIS415'
AND
      [E].[semester] = 'Fall2019'
AND
    [E].[GPA] >= [DT].[GPA]
```

Comment: I don't know if I follow all of the [E], [S], and especially [DT]. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: [E] and [S] are just aliases for the tables, completely optional. Rather than typing the table name out on each join you can reference it with something else. The DT is called a subquery returning the highest GPA for each class/semester. The outer query is then comparing all relevant Enrolments to that max GPA and only selecting the ones which are equal or greater (there won't be any greater than it). Have you tried running the query?

Comment: SELECT  Firstname, Lastname
    FROM    Students

            INNER JOIN Enrolls ON students.SID = Employees.SID
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT  MAX(GPA), CID, SID
                FROM    Enrolls
                GROUP BY
                        CID, SID
             ) DT
     ON  employees.CID = DT.CID
      AND employees.SID = DT.SID

    WHERE employees.CID = 'CIS415'
    AND employees.semester = 'Fall2019'
    AND employees.GPA >= DT.GPA


This is what I entered in and it gives me an error. Unknown Column 'employee.CID' in 'Where clause'.

Comment: I got it to work however, the answer is incorrect. Instead of giving me one name as the person with the top GPA with the given parameters, it just lists all the names of the people in the class.

Comment: You got an error indicating "unknown column" on "Employee.CID" because there is no "employee" table. My query doesn't reference that either. The query works, unless your database schema is different to what you indicated in your post.